# Wordpress display "welcome back" message after user account has x days of age or after x amount of effectuated logins?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to display a Welcome Back message to a user after he has logged in a certain amount of times or after his account is like 2 days old?

Currently I'm just displaying a Welcome message using this code:

```
add_action( 'login_form_middle', 'add_lost_password_link' );

if(!function_exists('vivid_login_page'))
{
  function vivid_login_page()
  {

      if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {


// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329256/access-first-name-and-last-name-from-user-register    
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     $first_name = $current_user->user_firstname; 
     $last_name = $current_user->user_lastname;
     
     
     print '<div class="calltoactioncontent"><span>Hello&nbsp;' . $first_name . "&nbsp;" . $last_name . '.&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span><a href="/my-account">My account&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span><a href="/wp-admin/profile.php">My profile</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=' . wp_logout_url() . '>Logout</a></span></div>';  
      }
    
        else { 
    print  '<div class="calltoactioncontent"><span class="bolddd">Hello visitor.&nbsp;</span><a href=' ."/my-account" . '>Sign in</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=' ."/my-account/registration/" . '>Register account</a></span></div>';  
      }
  }

  add_shortcode('vivid-login-page', 'vivid_login_page');
}
```

Comment: The registration date is stored directly in the wp_users table, so there is probably a method to fetch that from the user object. Not sure what sense _"after he has logged in a certain ammount of times"_ is supposed to make though - so I would log in five times, and then the fifth time I get your "welcome back" message shown? Why then, why was I not welcomed back on the previous logins already? But either way, the _number_ of logins does not get recorded by default, so that you would have to add yourself first.

Comment: How about account age?

Comment: What about it ...? I already said that the registration date is stored directly in the user data table, did I not?